# Unity Buttons making do letters

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I make buttons work like pressing "w" or "d" because I want to make an easy way to move the car in my game, any ideas how? I can use it as two big buttons on the Screen as UI and I will also do a "esc" button so they can go back to the pause menu. I arlready tried and its a script i have to write and im bad at it thanks for help!

Comment: WASD is not a proper method for your game. If a user wants to move in a diagonal direction, he/she will have to press two keys on the screen at the same time. This is a bad scenario for both pc and mobile. I recommend using a joystick.

Comment: but what if i just do so the right button is doing "w" and "d" or should i just do a right button for gas and two left buttons for turning. And also about the joystick how can i use it?

Comment: Using different button is related to your game design. However, if you are developing this kind of game, it may be difficult for the user to use these buttons with the joystick. It may be a good option if the vehicle moves automatically.

You can watch this tutorial for develop your own joystick: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bp2PiFC9sSs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using other buttons than w,a,s,d because these are already used in the InputManager for Horizontal and Vertical.

You can just check if the key for example "K" is pressed and then move your car

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K)) {
//your movement script

You could also create a button on ther UI Canvas and add an OnClick function in which your movement script is executed whenever you press the button on the canvas